# How to make a group of regex characters optional?

Tags: regex, option-type

I'm trying to create a regex that allows unicode letters, digits, -, and apostrophes where the first character is a letter or number, while subsequent characters can be letters, numbers, -, or '.  I think that my regex works fine except in the case where a user enters a single letter or number.  Is there anyway to make my 2+ characters to be optional?  Below is my current regex:

```
/^[\p{L}0-9]+[-\'\p{L}0-9']+$/u
```

Thanks!

-Eric

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob to regex and have seen the ? operator in other questions, but am not sure how to implement it.  Also, for the input/output, the user is supplying a $string and via php, I'm using preg_match($regex,$string) to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `?` you can use:

```
/^[\p{L}0-9]+[-\'\p{L}0-9']*$/u
```

to allow single alpha-numeric in input since `[-\'\p{L}0-9']*` means 0 or matches.